# check sdk version and if

Tags: android

I need check version of android and use if to runs one or other alertdialog. Using this code, "builder" bottom last if is not shared. What is best way to do this?

My code:

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES. HONEYCOMB) 
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        }
        else if (sdk >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES. HONEYCOMB)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, animazione);
        }

        builder.setView(view).create();
        TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoView1);
        builder.setCancelable(false); 
        builder.setPositiveButton("Chiudi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
                   tips = 0;
                   dialog.cancel();
            }  
            });  
        builder.show();     
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple, like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
{
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
}
else
{
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, animazione);
}
```

As *@Eric* points out, a simple `else` suffices since the `else if` is basically testing for the opposite condition than the `if`.

Comment: Should probably just turn that `else if` into `else` (for clarity's sake). +1 otherwise.

Comment: @K-ballo, with your code, builder.setView(view).create(); and other builder bottom if are not available (The local variable builder may not have been initialized)

Comment: @Pol Hallen: `builder` is always initialized, the conditions are opposite. But replace the `else if` with a single `else` and the dumb compiler won't complain...

Comment: @Pol Hallen: Is not your mistake, that mistake is on the compiler being dumb.